# APIs en Android para integrar Gmail

Tags: android, gmail

Estoy haciendo una app de Android en la que quiero integrar el envío de correo y además el poder recibir correos de Gmail.

Estuve buscando y encontré una API sacada por Google para Gmail, llamada Gmail API.

Lo leí y no entendí muy bien cómo funciona. Mis preguntas son:

1. ¿Alguien me podría dar sólo un resumen o un bosquejo superficial de cómo funciona esta API?
2. ¿Hay otra forma de integrar el correo electrónico en Android?